# Ubuntu 18.04 Lts automatically shutdown

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, shutdown

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 Lts . I had a error in boooting . My computer automatically shutdown during boooting . I solved that problem by changing grub file permanently adding  line in file /etc/default/grub "radeon.modeset=0" . After that my os work perfectly and boot on normally everytime.

But after that there is a new problem that my computer only work for 10- 15 minutes perfectly and then automatically shutdown suddenly during working . (Work on application like file folder , browsers) .

Even i am doing nothing on computer and not opening any application and just keep it in lock mode , it automatically shutdown after 20- 30 minutes.
Please help me in this problem

Comment: It sounds like a hardware issue to me. There is no Ubuntu 18, there is Ubuntu Core 18 (*yy* format), 18.04 LTS & 18.10 (*yy.mm* for main releases), so the closest by name is you're using Ubuntu Core 18?  (but I suspect not). I would check your hardware logs for temperature & other conditions; if temperature thresholds are reached the hardware shuts down to protect itself & your OS (whatever it is) is not told; the PSU just shuts down.  Usually the event won't be in hardware-logs, but the warnings pre-shutdown are usually present.  (better hardware has more complete logs)

Comment: On starting computer temperature  around  between 60 -75  Celsius and then increase to 85 . And while using application (browsers , file folder )  temperature gradually increases around 90 Celsius  within 20 to 30 minutes . I am using lmsensors and psensors for temperature

Comment: Sounds like it's getting too hot; and when the hardware detects threshold it grounds a wire & PSU shuts down power instantly.  On good boxes lots of sensors are available to provide stats & records of these events (easiest to view in hardware-bios in my experience), low-end consumer boxes tend to provide little logs but you can still watch the details if you boot & remain in bios-config.  I use an old [home] hp box for testing that has heat issues; it has no fancy logs, but even its bios let me turn it on, detect & learn the issue then adjust fan settings (making it noisy) to limit the problem

Comment: I suspect the issue is your hardware, Ubuntu has nothing to do with it (other than it is what is running on your hardware).   You could boot a 'live' distro (possibly something other than what you use) & try using it... if my suspicions are correct, it'll just shutdown when [temperature] threshold is reached without (OS/you) being told.  This should confirm a hardware issue (relating to heat).  If however it only occurs in Ubuntu - it could be a config issue in your 18.04 LTS setup.  Do a cap-check inside your box maybe (cpu & OS used in my opinion are immaterial)

Comment: My processor is Intel i3 cpu M 350 @2.27 GHz Ram 4 gb. And Graphic intel ironmake mobile . Laptop Lenovo y460 ideapad .My fan is  working perfectly ( but noisy) and I am using laptop cooler

Comment: How to solve this config problem and prevent from shutting down

Comment: If it's your hardware as I expect - you can't.  It's done that way to protect hardware life & ensure it lives to end-of-warranty-period.  You are limited to whatever controls the machine bios/hardware provide, which is heaps for enterprise level hardware, but almost nothing on consumer grade equipment.  I already suggested creating a thumb-drive of another OS & trying it for a day to confirm it's hardware, or it's a Ubuntu setting that needs change. That's what I'd do next (*and it wouldn't be anything like Ubuntu 18.04, even if not as far away as a freebsd 'live'*)

Comment: @guiverc is right - you seem to have broken or defective hardware, not a config problem. Your temperatures are much too high. Ubuntu is not designed to run on broken or defective hardware. Get your hardware fixed, then Ubuntu will work.

Comment: Heat related problem. Open the laptop/desktop and blow out the dust, and it'll probably work again... worst case... the CPU thermal paste needs refresh... and without the "radeon.modeset=0" mod.

Comment: Thank you so much @guiverc and thank you all guys